# How to ignor blanks to return return the closest date to today from a column?

Tags: date, excel-formula, max, aggregate

I am trying to return the closest date to today from a column with "submission dates". however, there are some blank cells in that column. I have used:

```
=LARGE(B1:B17,1)
```

but it give me an error (assuming this is because of the blank cells).
I also tried the aggregate formula

```
=AGGREGATE(14,3,$B$1:$B$7,1)
```

but also getting an error #NUM!

I also tried this:

```
=MAX(IF($B$1:$B$7<>"",$B$1:$B$7))
```

but it returns a zero (not sure if the max formula is appropriate for dates though)

I am not sure if this has something to do with the formatting of dates? this is what my table looks like and Ideally I'd like the formula to return 1/18/2021 (which is closest to today from the list).

| Column B |
| --- |
| 1/1/2020 |
| 1/1/2021 |
| 1/1/2019 |
| 1/1/2018 |
| blank |
| blank |
| 1/18/2021 |

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would guess that your "dates" are stored as text and not true dates.  You will need to parse the values to convert to true dates, changing the formatting is not enough.

Comment: thanks, Scott. The submission date is added automatically when the user inputs data. the submission date itself is designed to show the previous friday to the date the user inputs data, and the formula we use for the submission date is this:
=TEXT(NOW()-WEEKDAY(NOW(),16),"yyyy-mm-dd"). Do you think this might be creating the problem?

Comment: it is definitely the problem.  do: `=NOW()-WEEKDAY(NOW(),16)` only and format the cell itself to the `yyyy-mm-dd`.  TEXT() returns text that looks like a date and not a true date, which is a number.